# Nested list not working

Tags: html, css, html-lists

This is my code. The prob is that the list is not nesting properly. I added a padding-left, but the number in left margin doesn't go away.

```css
#li {
  padding-left: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<h3>My grocery store</h3>
<hr></hr>
<p>Following items are available at my store:</p>
<ol>
  <li>Sugar</li>
  <li>Chocolates :
    <li id="li">Toblerone</li>
    <li id="li">Nestle</li>
  </li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Other food items..</li>
</ol>
<img src="C:/Users/James007/Desktop/shop.JPEG"></img>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add another `<ol>` tag inside the `<li>` tag, because the list is nested inside a list item.  See the **[W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists#Nesting_lists)**.

```html
<h3>My grocery store</h3>
<hr></hr>
<p>Following items are available at my store:</p>
<ol>
  <li>Sugar</li>
  <li>Chocolates :
    <ol>
      <li>Toblerone</li>
      <li>Nestle</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Other food items..</li>
</ol>
<img src="C:/Users/James007/Desktop/shop.JPEG"></img>
```

Also, remove `</hr>` and `</img>`, as empty elements don't have a closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

As a nested list is considered to be a list within a list, you have to open another `<ol>` or `<ul>` inside the big one. With this you don't need the `id` tag.

By the way, an `id` tag is supposed to be used only once in an HTML page. For multiple uses, it's better to use `class`. It's done with a point (`.`) instead of the hash (`#`) in the CSS. See [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

To finish with, as stated by The Pragmatick, `<img />` and `<hr />` tag are self-closing.

See code below :

```css
.li {
  padding-left: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<h3>My grocery store</h3>
<hr />
<p>Following items are available at my store:</p>
<ol>
  <li>Sugar</li>
  <li>Chocolates :
    <ul>
      <li class="li">Toblerone</li>
      <li class="li">Nestle</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Other food items..</li>
</ol>
<img src="C:/Users/James007/Desktop/shop.JPEG" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1 is correct.

To do nested lists you have to put a list inside a list. So you were missing the **ol** inside the **li**. Which makes sense doesn't it?

Here you have a video that writes a nested list https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTKonB86J2s

The technical reference
http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists

```
<ol>
  <li>Sugar</li>
  <li>Chocolates :
     <ol>
       <li>Toblerone</li>
       <li>Nestle</li>
     </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Other food items..</li>
</ol>
```